# Необходимо найти наибольшее из 3-ёх чисел. Каждое из чисел не превышает 10^100

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Код не проходит если подставить максимально возможное значение на входе.

```
  var
  a, b, c: integer;
begin
  read(a, b, c);
  if (a > b) and (a > c) then writeln(a)
  else
  if (b > a) and (b > c) then writeln(b)
  else
  if (c > a) and (c > b) then writeln(c)
  else 
  if (c=b) and (c>a) then writeln(c)
  else 
  if (c=a) and (c>b) then writeln(c)
  else
  if (a=b) and (a>c) then writeln(a)
  else 
  if (a=b) and (b=c) then writeln(a);
 end.
```

Нужна хотя-бы идея,как решить задачу.

Comment: Используйте строки, а не числа

Comment: String'ом всё равно не влезет, а других типов не нашёл

Comment: Входные данные мы должны сами придумать?

Comment: Да, от 1 до 10^100

Comment: Что "от 1 до 10^100"? Вы понимаете, что запись `10^100` для паскалевского `read` бессмыслена? Как заданы входные данные? Приведите пример[ы].

Comment: Да знаю,но не писать же 10...00 Пример :189285 283 4958439238923098349024

Comment: массив и цикл вам поможет. Я не помню, а есть ли в Паскале готовая функция сортировки для массивов? Если есть можете обойтись без цикла, сразу готовой сортировкой.

Comment: @Bulson Ему сначала надо с типом данных разобраться.

Comment: @Igor верно заметили.

Answer (score 2):

```
var
  a, b, c: string;
  a1, b1, c1: string;
  strL: integer;
begin
  read(a, b, c);

  strL := Length(a);
  if Length(b) > strL then
    strL := Length(b);
  if Length(c) > strL then
    strL := Length(c);
  a1 := StringOfChar(strL - Length(a), '0') + a;
  b1 := StringOfChar(strL - Length(b), '0') + b;
  c1 := StringOfChar(strL - Length(c), '0') + c;

  if (a1 > b1) and (a1 > c1) then 
    WriteLn(a)
  else if (b1 > c1) then 
    WriteLn(b)
  else
    WriteLn(c);
end.
```

Answer (score -2):

Я передал вашу программу, убрав лишние функции (начало и конец) и всё соединил между собой.

```
program pas; {Начало програми}
  var
     a, b, c: integer;{}
begin{начало основной програми}
    Writeln('Введите дание a, b, c');{Виод на екран сообщения}
    read(a, b, c);{Ввод з клавиатури даных}
  begin 
    if a > b then 
    if a > c then writeln(a,' a>c'){Проверка ли А наибольшое число}
  end; 
  begin
    if b>a then
    if b>c then writeln(b,' b>c'){Проверка ли B наибольшое число}
 end;
 begin
    if c>a then
    if c>b then writeln(c,' c>b');{Проверка ли C наибольшое число}
 end;
 begin
    if a=b then writeln(a,' a=c');
    if b=c then writeln(b,' b=c');
    if a=c then writeln(a,' a=c');{Проверки на равность чисел, например если A=B виведет А и соответствующое сообщение}
 end;
end.{Конец основной програми}
```

Comment: кхм, кхм, как Вы собираетесь поместить в `integer` число порядка 10 в 10-той степени? И я уже чудесно ответил на вопрос.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin дополнение додано, тем кто только начал в этом языке разбираться должно быть понятно с этими комментариями

Comment: К сожалению, ответ от этого правильным не стал.

Comment: @Igor введите в компиляторе и попробуйте, всё работает и наглядно написано, а со сменной "Length" я всего несколько раз сталкивался за 2 годика обучения (в учебном учреждение).

Comment: Из вопроса: "Код не проходит если подставить максимально возможное значение на входе." Вы понимаете, что это значит? Что такое "сменная Length"?

Comment: Я проверил даже с 100000 в начале и ничего... Я нею почти не пользуюсь там было раз или два за два года...